# RAM boot issues for a P8P67

Tags: memory, computer-building, post

I'm in the middle of my first computer build and have hit a brick wall. Having assembled (and re-assembled) all of the components, I'm still getting a POST error (a long beep followed by two short beeps) saying I have no memory. I have tried two different types of memory, both of which are on the QVL for my Asus P8P67 Rev 3.1 motherboard. I every combination of sticks in all 4 slots, clearing the RTC RAM between each attempt and running MEMOK! as well. Everything else seems to run fine; all fans run continuously, hard drives fire up, case lights working, except that the RAM is not detected.

Any suggestions on what I should do? I'd appreciate any advice.

Motherboard: Asus P8P67 Rev 3.1
Processor: Intel Core i-5 2500k
RAM: 2 different versions of G.Skill ripsaw 4GB DDR3 memory, one set at 1333 MHz and one set at 1600 Mhz (used separately)
Video Card: GeForce GTX 560 Ti
PS: Seasonic S12 II Bronze 520W 80Plus Power Supply

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all other hardware, including hard drives and video cards.

It's also possible your motherboard is defective.